# Magento2: New with magento cloud. How to run the commands on cloud environment

Tags: magento2-cloud

I have cloned the git on my local system, Now how to run the commands for cloud site. How to do this?

As I have CLI for this, But I don't know how I can use this?

Please suggest me for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Install the magento-cloud CLI.

```
curl -sS https://accounts.magento.cloud/cli/installer | php
```

Add magento-cloud CLI to the bash profile.

```
export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.magento-cloud/bin
```

Consult operating system documentation for details.

Reload the updated bash profile.

```
. ~/.bash_profile
```

To initiate the CLI, call `magento-cloud` and enter your Cloud account credentials when prompted.

```
magento-cloud




Welcome to Magento Cloud!
Please log in using your Magento Cloud account.
Your email address or username:
```

Verify the magento-cloud command is in your path. The following example lists the available commands.

```
magento-cloud list
```

source : https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/reference/cli-ref-topic.html